# "Bitte ich Sie, das alles aufzugeben."

Tags: translation, german-to-english

The sentence in the title is taken from Rilke's "Briefe an einen jungen Dichter".

The common translation is: "I beg you to stop doing that sort of thing."
I feel the second part of it deserves a more accurate translation. How do you suggest to translate it?

Comment: Why do you think the translation is not accurate? And isn't that a question about the english language?

Comment: @userunknown, pretty much because "that sort of thing" seems kind of cumbersome translation for "das alles". I guess you can see it as a question about the english language as well, but it's mainly about a german-to-english translation.

Comment: I would use "please give it up". It is nearly mirror translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking the text from [here](http://www.rilke.de/briefe/170203.htm).

The original sentence reads

> Nun (...) bitte ich Sie, das alles aufzugeben.

A translation that is closer to the original words would be

> Now, I beg you to give up doing all that.

"all that" in this context refers to the recipient of this letter asking Rilke and others to critique his poems.

The meaning doesn't really change if you replace "all that" with "that sort of thing" and "aufgeben" means "stop doing" here. This usage of "aufgeben" is very formal though and would probably never be heard outside of written letters.